# Postgres index into an array column using another column

Tags: postgresql

## Setup

I have the following tables:

```
Questions
 - id      (INT)
 - quizId  (INT)
 - text    (TEXT)          
 - options (JSON[])      

Answers
 - id      (INT)
 - questionId (INT)
 - choice  (INT)
```

"options" is an array of JSON objects:

```
{"{\"text\": \"Text for option 1\", \"correct\": false}", "{\"text\": \"Text for option 2\", \"correct\": true}"}
```

## Question

I would basically like to get the value of "correct", given "choice" (an index), after joining those two tables.

The pseudocode for what I'm trying to achieve would be:

```
select "Questions"."options"["Answers"."choice"] from <JOIN THOSE TABLES>;
```

Comment: How is this different from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59718758/sql-query-with-complex-filter)? Please avoid posting duplicates, instead you can wait for answers, or update your question to improve it somehow.

Comment: @GMB Well, I simplified it for myself and others by taking out the `filter` part. Seemed different enough.

Comment: I suppose I can delete the other

Comment: I suspect that proper sample data for both tables, along with the expected results (as tabular text), would make your question more appealing. Also your other question was showing your attemped SQL query, which is always a good thing; you might want to reincorporate it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not just pseudocode, [that's exactly how you write array subscripts](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-ACCESSING). Now only the `JOIN` condition is missing:

```
SELECT "Questions"."options"["Answers"."choice"] AS choosen_answer_option
FROM "Questions" JOIN "Answers" ON ("Questions".id = "Answers"."questionId")
```

Comment: Thanks! So the final part is that I need to get "correct" from those objects. I'm able to pull out the array item, but now I need to get the field from that item!

Comment: Use [the json `->`/`->>` operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE) for that, e.g. `(options[choice]->>'correct')::boolean`